# How does Google Backup services get to know my Wi-Fi password on Android

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-backup-service

AFAIK our Wi-Fi passwords will be backed up when Google performs its backup operation. However the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file is owned by the `wifi` user and is in the `wifi` group, so even the `system` user has no access to it. There must be some APIs exposed to at least those system apps, and I wonder what are those. It is highly appreciated to provide codes from https://android.googlesource.com/ as evidences. Thank you.